# Scale plugin with xfce4-dockbarx-plugin

Tags: compiz, xfce, dockbarx

I'm running xubuntu 16.04 with xfce4-dockbarx-plugin and compiz activated. Unfortunately, I cannot get the scale plugin to work with dockbarx.
Following https://github.com/M7S/dockbarx I need to activate the scale plugin and the glib extension in compiz as well as the compiz plugin in dockbarx.

The scale plugin is activated, but I cannot find the glib extension in ccsm nor can I find the compiz plugin in the dockbarx preferences. Is this even possible with the dockbarx plugin / xfce-panel and if so, whats missing?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you enable the "show preview" option in the "window list" DockbarX preferences, and, as per the FAQ in the link you referenced, enable compiz-scale and in the Compiz settings manager enable KWin compatibility.

Not sure what the DBX author means with that "glib" stuff, but the procedure above did the trick for me.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that did not work either. The dockbarx preview runs with the KDE compatibility. However, the scale functions still does not work :/

Answer (score 0):

Here are some screenshots of how I did it. Make sure you have the equivalents enabled on your setup.

[image]
<sup>**DockbarX Settings → window list**</sup>

[image]
<sup>**DockbarX Settings keyboard shortcuts**</sup>

[image]
<sup>**CompizConfig Settings**</sup>

[image]
<sup>**Firefox web browser**</sup>

Sorry about the non-English, but it should be rather obvious what you need to click with your own language settings. It works for me.

edit: sorry, I didn't read your comment closely enough. Yeah, the unity-like feature. That seems bugged for me as well.